# iOS - Duplicate Symbol Google Core and Firebase Performance

Tags: ios, firebase

I have a problem with my pods:

```
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
pod 'Firebase/Crash'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Google/Core'
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod 'GoogleAPIClientForREST/Drive', '~> 1.2.1'
```

When I try to run app I get this error:

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`duplicate symbol __ZN8farmhash15Hash128WithSeedEPKcmNSt3__14pairIyyEE in:`

`/Folder/Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a(farmhash.o)`

`/Folder/Pods/FirebasePerformance/Frameworks/FirebasePerformance.framework/FirebasePerformance(farmhash_1feb16fbc53729c6445bb1d31fe78fdc.o)`

Can anyone tell me how to fix the problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a symbol collision between the generated contents from the Firebase/Performance and Google/Core pod specifications.

I see three options:

1. Remove Google/Core from Podfile
2. If Google/Core functionality is needed, convert it to Firebase and remove Google/Core from Podfile
3. Use `lipo` and `ar` tools to remove farmhash.o from Pods/Google/Libraries/libGGLCore.a and reconstruct it.

Comment: I remove Google/Core. Thank you so much.